# Is it possible to use NGINX cache instead of RackCache?

Tags: ruby, nginx, rack

I have configured my site on the server to use Rack Cache. But I was wondering if it is possible to use NGINX instead of that as I think NGINX cache would be faster? I am using NGINX as the web server and Thin as the application server. But I am not sure how I can use NGINX to serve the cached files instead of through Rack Cache. 
Right now, all i have done is use the following in my config.ru and have configured the caching using the routing library's feature.

```
require 'rack-cache'
use Rack::Cache
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to use Nginx as a caching solution this would be configured outside the application. Rack cache is meant to be more portable and independent. These articles should be of som use if you really want to go with Nginx caching but until you truly need it I am not sure it makes sense. [Speed up Rails with Nginx’s Reverse Proxy Cache](https://mattbrictson.com/nginx-reverse-proxy-cache) or [Nginx Caching](https://serversforhackers.com/nginx-caching)

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky. the site seems pretty fast with just the rack cache and i don't think nginx would be needed, but i am still wondering if i am missing anything. do you know if it is possible to create the cache files using rack cache and serve those using nginx? is it possible to save the cache files somewhere inside the 'public' directory and make it serve via nginx?